# Create Python List using a True/False expression check?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, expression

Looking to generate a Python list that uses an `if` statement to check whether a number is even or odd. If even take the List value as '1' and if odd take the list value as '0'.

Progress to date:

List1 = [x for x in range(0,99) if x % 2 == 0]

However, this only generates a list of even numbers. When I change the expression to add an else check I get a syntax error. Any help appreciated.

List1 = [1 for x in range(0,99) if x % 2 == 0 else 0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a filter, where you want to alter the left-hand-side expression instead, using a *conditional expression*:

```
[1 if x % 2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(99)]
```

This can be simplified to:

```
[1 - (x % 2) for x in range(99)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Spent some time struggling with this issue and you've showed me how simple the syntax really is. In terms of left/right hand side of expressions and filtering, is there any good content on web which explains this for a beginner? None of the basic expressions I've encountered to date in lists seem to deal with this? I did try to create a function first, and then call the function within the list to generate. Struggled with this too:

Comment: ` def odd_even():
    for x in range(0,99):
     if x % 2 == 0:
      x = 1
     else:
      x = 0

    List1 = [odd_even()]

    print(List1) `

Comment: @MarkGuk: this doesn't really work in comments, but it looks like you are not returning anything from the function. You'd still have to build a list *in the function itself*, or read up on generator functions (which is perhaps a little too advanced at this stage).

Comment: how do I format the above text as code?

Comment: @MarkGuk: you can't; you can use `backticks` (\`, no spaces between the backtick and the text) to format the line but you cannot have newlines or indentation. Comments are not for code.

Answer (score 2):

Change the if else condition present inside the list_comprehension like below.

```
>>> [1  if x % 2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(0,99)]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

This would print `1` for even numbers and 0 for odd numbers.